# Error when declaring an array without specifying size initially: <error-type> Crew::flightAttendants Incomplete type is not allowed

Tags: java, c++, arrays

So given this class in **C++**...

```cpp
    //C++ CODE    
        class Crew {
            Person flightAttendants[]; //Error: <error-type> Crew::flightAttendants Incomplete type is not allowed.
            Person captain, firstOfficer;
        public:
            Crew(Person, Person, Person);
        };
```

I'd like to declare **(but ***NOT*** at first initialize)** the `flightAttendants[]` array without specifying what would be it's length **beforehand** (*I just want to specify its size after*). Just like **Java**, for example, in which we could do:

```java
    //JAVA CODE    
        class Lamp {
            private int nLightBulbs;
            private boolean lightBulbs[];
        
            Lamp(int nLightBulbs) {
                this.nLightBulbs = nLightBulbs;
                this.lightBulbs = new boolean[nLightBulbs];
            }
        }
```

That's the question.

Comment: The compiler needs to know how much space the class data takes up. How many bytes does an array of unknown size take up? Potentially all of it. Potentially none of it. You need to specify a size if you want an array. You can either OVER specify (make it as large as the largest array will be) or you can use a dynamic container (such as a `std::vector<Person> flightAttendants;`)  - this latter one is how Java arrays work I believe, and is the canonical way to make dynamically sized containers of elements in C++.

Comment: You can't do this in C++.  This is what [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is for.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> Person flightAttendants[];
> ```

you wanted for instance

```
 Person * flightAttendants;
```

then like in Java you have :

> ```
> this.lightBulbs = new boolean[nLightBulbs];
> ```

in C++ do

```
 flightAttendants = new Person[...expected size...];
```

But it is very more practical to use a `std::vector`

```
 std::vector<Person> flightAttendants;
```

for a lot of reasons including to be able to get its size/to resize it, and to not have to manage the pointer used in `Person * flightAttendants` (even there are other ways to manage it in a secure way)

---

Note in Java you always manipulate pointer to instances, in C++ we have the choice and the previous array/vector do not memorize pointer to instances of *Person* but instances of *Person*